# Why is my serial chart is not showing the expected graph when given my data points?

Tags: charts, amcharts

Im creating a serial chart and passing along some data points. However I expect that, given my data, each line in the graph should appear as a staircase going up from left to right. Instead I get a garbled mess. Here's my code with my included data points. Also, the graph seems to work fine when I include only the first 5 data points, however the moment I add the 6th data point the graph disappears. Seems like those issues are related but I can't figure out how.

First five data points (chart starts off fine):

```
{
"date": "2016-7-15",
"value4": 20,
"value1002": 10
}, {
"date": "2016-7-16",
"value4": 20,
"value1002": 10
}, {
"date": "2016-7-17",
"value4": 20,
"value1002": 10
}, {
"date": "2016-7-18",
"value4": 20,
"value1002": 10
}, {
"date": "2016-7-19",
"value4": 20,
"value1002": 10
}
```

and the sixth data point (chart breaks):

```
{
"date": "2016-7-20",
"value4": 30,
"value1002": 10
}
```

Here is a fiddle with all of my data points included:

http://jsfiddle.net/qzdwq0f3/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your `dataDateFormat` doesn't match your date format. The `dataDateFormat` only supports two digit months and two digit days  [per the documentation](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/formatting-dates/), so the parser gets confused when it sees single digit values that aren't prepended with a zero (note that your first five dates are intepreted as incorrect dates in December when you comment out the rest of the dates). You need to prepend your single digit months and days with zero a so that your dates are interpreted correctly.

Here's an updated version of your fiddle that has YYYY-MM-DD dates in your `dataProvider`: http://jsfiddle.net/qzdwq0f3/4/